# Correct headers for Chromecast

Tags: nginx, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to play a .mp4 video hosted on my NGINX server with the Default Receiver App for Chromecast.

I'm able to cast the videos used in their example apps just fine, but my own video fails without returning any error. I'm guessing this has to do with the CORS configuration on my server.

I'm using [this config](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html) to enable cors on my server. I've tried adding gstatic.com to allowed origins aswell but it doesn't help. I took a look on the headers [one of their example videos](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) and tried to reverse engineer what headers I'm missing and still can't get it to work.

What headers do I need to enable for the Chromecast to play my files?

Answer (score 0):

The server that hosts the content needs to set the necessary CORS headers for playback to work.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm linking to my CORS configuration in the question.

Comment: Can you also explicitly add support for the HTTP HEAD requests and see if that makes a difference.